# Bumpy jigsaw type data into curve data

Tags: excel, matlab, difference

I have a problem I solved in Excel but I am completely stuck in Matlab.

A weight measuring how much liquid I pump is refilled when its almost empty. Here is a picture

[image: plot]

Now I want to see it in one motion, not like a jigsaw. Here is my solution, doing it manually in Excel:

[image: plot2]

Now to Matlab where this should be done automatically: I know how to index the row before and after I have the bumps, but I'm kind of stuck now. I do d=diff(x) ok and now I can replace the high peaks when the bumps occur (i=d(:,1)>0) with 0 so it never happened. And how do I translate it back? Somehow "undiff(x)"? im completely lost.

Here's an extract of my x:

```
2533,30
3540,00
3484,90
3430,00
3375,00
3320,20
3265,60
3210,60
3155,80
3101,20
3046,50
2991,70
2937,00
2882,50
2828,10
2773,80
2719,30
2664,90
2610,50
2556,10
2501,60
3508,00
3454,00
3399,70
3352,10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
temp = [0; diff(x)];
temp(temp < 0) = 0;
y = x - cumsum(temp);
y(temp > 0) = interp1(y, find(temp > 0) + 0.5);
plot(y);
```

Comment: almost there. needed only to subtract w(1) from all. I am almost perfectly happy, if it wasnt for the <0 = 0 term. it is in fact not 0 but i make this assumption. in reality it is in a similar magnitude as the diff(w) around this point. an interpolation between then points excluding 0 would do the trick, any idea for this? 

i imagine it to look like:

    temp = [0; diff(w)];
    temp(temp < 0) = 0; % here the interpolation between the value before and after the zero
    y=w-cumsum(temp)-w(1);
    plot(y);

and many thanks for the help so far! im sorry i need more reputation to vote you up.

Comment: I've changed my answer to include interpolation to the "zero points" by considering the previous and the next point. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

hen using the default `plot()` function, matlab will automatically draw a line plot and connect each point in the data you are plotting.

Instead it seems like you just need to plot the points individually and unconnected. So if you are currently doing something like `plot(x)` or `area(x)` instead try `plot(x,'o')`.  This will cause Matlab to plot the points individually without connecting them as lines.

If you'd like to change the marker type used to plot each point, use `doc linespec` to get more info.

Comment: thats not it. my issue is not plotting, its taking the value 3540, making it zero+the last from before the bump, that would be 2533,3. and also, add 2533,3 to every single value afterwards. until the next bump. where again it needs to be 0+ the value before bump...its really easy to explain it but i cant write the code!